# Tomcat 9 error with spring app: the requested resource [/registration] is not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am making java spring app with springboot, tomcat 9 and Intellij IDEA. I want to use registration() method with @GetMapping("/registration") to go to registration.jsp. But if i go to http://localhost:8080/registration, i see error "The requested resource [/registration] is not available" with description "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists".

I thought that it's problem with tomcat so i also tried tomcat 10 but it didn't help me. What's problem?

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>spring_app</name>
</project>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

**RegistrationController:**

```
package com.boots.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class RegistrationController {
@GetMapping("/registration")
    public String registration() {
        return "registration";
    }
}
```

**registration.jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sign in</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Welcome to registration page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**MvcConfig:**

```
package com.boots.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/news").setViewName("news");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your APP is named "registration" therefore it resides in the web app folder named registration!  The registration.jsp is a "page" and would be address called http://localhost:8080/registration/registration.jsp , it is not an index.html or index.jsp so is not a domain or sub domain pointer, it must be written completely in the address bar.

Comment: However, more usually, that error message means there is a problem with the web.xml such an error or malformed markup web.xml

Comment: @SamuelMarchant, in appliction.properties file i set spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/ (folder with all my jsp files) and spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp. As i understand, after typing URL: localhost:8080/registration, method registration() will be started, and this method return "registration" string. So spring will check .properties file and find registration.jsp. Or no?

Comment: Take a look at this page around 2/3rds down the middle to understand Tomcat as a java web application server  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VipRDFmIWYBoaYbzYx0G70jyMKlSBIGe/view?usp=drive_link  (it operates) however, "somewhere inside localhost:8080" will be a folder "registration" that will be a web application. AFAIK As Far As I Know , if "registration" EVER pointed to a method e.g. registration() by URL you would be using WSDL Web Services and probably REST paths BUT none of that is what you say you represent anywhere in your application, you only represent a standard simple .jsp web-app

Comment: In retrospect to that, I should said too that your web app web.xml would label the registration.jsp as a welcome-file XML element too for it to be able to direct to that page